# Looking for a list of values for $\xi^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, riemann-zeta

I'm looking for a list of values for ${\xi^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})}$, where $\xi^{(n)}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of the Riemann's $\xi$ function or, alternatively, some implementation of ${\xi^{(n)}(s)}$, eventually in Mathematica.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "eventually in *Mathematica*" - Try `D[RiemannXi[z], {z, n}]` in the current version of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1):

For numerical values for the first 3 derivatives, see the "Relations and positivity results for the derivatives of the Riemann ξ function" by Coffey. Integral formulas are also given.

Answer (score 0):

For computing $\xi^{(2n)}(1/2)$ for only one $n$ you should use  $$\xi(s) =\frac{s (s-1)}{2} \Lambda(s)$$ where
$$\Lambda(s)= \Gamma(s/2)\pi^{-s/2} \zeta(s)= \int_0^\infty (\theta(x)-1) x^{s/2-1}dx\qquad\qquad \\ \qquad = \frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s}+\int_1^\infty (x^{s/2-1}+x^{(1-s)/2-1})(\theta(x)-1)dx \\ \theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x} = x^{-1/2} \theta(1/x)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

---

Also why would you need $\xi^{(2n)}(1/2)$ ?

Comment: I'm playing with this $$\xi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi^{(2n)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) }{(2n)!}\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}$$.

Comment: @Neves So you don't need $\xi^{(2n)}(1/2)$ ? $\zeta(s),\xi(s),Z(t), \zeta^{(n)}(s), \theta(x)$ are implemented in mathematica.